# Apache Dynamic Virtual Host with SSL

Tags: centos, mod-rewrite, apache-2.2

I have the following in my httpd.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *
    UseCanonicalName Off
    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log vcommon
    VirtualDocumentRoot /web-data/vhosts/%0/httpdocs
    VirtualScriptAlias  /web-data/vhosts/%0/httpdocs
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This works great for dynamic hosting. However, I can't figure out how to make https requests work the same way. What do I need to add to this so that https and http for the same domain request get sent to the same folder?

Answer (score 3):

It is not technically possible with Apache2 to do this without a wildcard SSL certificate as Apache will have only 1 certificate to serve. I.e. your certificate will say it's for "myxtx.com" yet the request will be for "mydomain2.com".

See [NameBasedSSLVHosts](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts)

However, it is possible using some extension but this is too complicated to explain all in one post here. So here is a link: [NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI)